# A problem with my project what is the function of getDeclareFields return $jacocoData？

Tags: java, jacoco, reflect

code:

```
Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

obj is a class which has 2 fields .

```
public class NullInfo implements Data {

    @Idx(0)
    private Integer index;

    @Idx(1)
    private String  fieldName;
}
```

interface Data  is empty .

my problem is :
The field length is expected to be only 2.
[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCKD2.png)

what is $jacocoData？

Comment: Pleas replace your images with text.

Comment: Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

Comment: It doesn't help to understand your problem. Explain what you observe, add suitable code and maybe someone will be able to help you. As for now I have no idea what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

> what is `$jacocoData`?

quoting [JaCoCo FAQ](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html):

> #### My code uses reflection. Why does it fail when I execute it with JaCoCo?
>
> To collect execution data JaCoCo instruments the classes under test which adds two members to the classes: A private static field `$jacocoData` and a private static method `$jacocoInit()`. Both members are marked as **synthetic**.
>
> Please change your code to ignore synthetic members. This is a good practice anyways as also the Java compiler creates synthetic members in certain situation.

Method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#isSynthetic() allows to determine synthetic fields.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is caused when you run code coverage with Jacoco.

**Root Cause:**

jacoco will add a static field to your class for the reason @Godin has explained.

**Solution:**

you need to use Java reflection only on 'original' fields.
You can either explicitly exclude the field named '$jacocoData', or you can use annotation as the filter, e,g.

```
Field field = fields[i];
Idx annotation = field.getAnnotation(Idx.class);
if (annotation == null) {
    continue;
}
```